# Ampscript Retrieve XSL using HTTPGet

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i am newbee to SFMC and struggling to create my first Email .
i have uploaded xsl file in Portfolio folder which i want to call in AMPScript at runtime and pass it in TransformXML Function  as a parameter . i am using HTTPGet to retrieve the xsl file and store it in a variable . 
Can anyone please tell how to find the path of the xsl file from portfolio Folder .
If i see the properties of any image in Portfolio i am able to see the URL, CustomerKey,ID  etc then why i cant see the URL of XSL file when i look into the XSL properties.

Comment: Hi Suman, please let me know if my answer was suitable, or if you need further detail to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the content structure of you XLS file, the [**GetPortfolioItem**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/getportfolioitem5/) AMPScript function may work for you.

I was able to output the contents of a CSV file in Portfolio using the following:

```
%%=v(GetPortfolioItem("MyCSVFile"))=%%
```

Comment: I am able to see all xsl uploaded file and their path in classic content ... I couldn't see the xsl file path in content builder